# Hidding input field when autocomplete is done

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a form that gets information from the database, and I want to hide one input if this is not empty.

```
<label for="email">Email *</label>
<input onBlur="verifyEmail()" id='email' type="email" name="email" autocomplete="email" required value=<%= user.email %> >
```

the value the input it's getting is user.email, I want to make it as if it grabs information then hide it.

I already tried

```
if(input#email != ''){
    $('#email input').attr('style', 'display:none');
}
if('input#email' != null){
    $('#email input').attr('style', 'display:none');
}
```

But none of this seems to be working.

Comment: instead of checking for if(input#email != ''){, you would need to get the value of the input field like $('#email').val() !=''. Then to hide, jquery has build in function .hide();

Comment: @CanerAkdeniz thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your selector with an `id or a class` so it will be easy for you to select and

jquery:

```
if($(".email").val() !== "") 

 /* do something */
```

javascript:

```
if(document.querySelector(".email").value !== "")

  /* do something */
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try with this:

```
if($(‘#email’).val()==“”)
     //do
```

Or

```
if($(‘#email’).text()==“”)
    //do
```

You should insert after # tag the id of input type and you get the value (or the text) of the label